# Critical points of dot product on sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n),b=(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ and $(a,b) =\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$ be the standard dot product in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $A$ be a symmetric operator and consider the function $(Ax,x)$ on sphere. So, how to prove that its critical points are eigenvectors of operator $A$. And when is the critical points non-degenerate?

Comment: Solve $\nabla f(x)=0$ for $f(x)=\frac{(Ax,x)}{(x,x)}$.

Comment: @Surb why is this proof ?

Comment: Well $f(x)=(A\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x,x)}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x,x)}})$ for all x, so the "critical points" you are look for are precisely the solutions to $\nabla f(x)=0$. I let you do this computation and believe that you'll be able to conclude easily from there. (Note that using the Lagrange multiplier method will give you the same).

Comment: @Surb Why do we take this function? and how to calculate this, sorry I'm so stupid

Comment: This is known as Rayleigh quotient. As to the why this one, is a more difficult question. In short, the symmetry guarantees that there is $g\colon\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ such that $\nabla g(x)=2Ax=(A+A^T)x$ (in facts, $g(x)=(Ax,x)$). So, when constraining $g$ on the sphere, by Lagrange, you know that the critical points satisfy $\nabla g(x)=\lambda x/\|x\|_2=\tilde \lambda x$.

Comment: @Surb When we constraining g on sphere we get $f$?  And you probably wanted to write$ \nabla g(x)=\lambda x/\|x\|^2=\tilde \lambda x$?

Comment: Well $\max_{\|x\|=1} (Ax,x)=\max_{x\neq 0} (Ax/\|x\|,x/\|x\|)=\max_{x\neq 0} (Ax,x)/(x,x)$.

Comment: @Surb and therefore we take this function, right? And how to see when her the critical points is nondegenerate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical points of $x\mapsto (Ax,x)$ on the unit sphere are the critical points of the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) of $A$:

Note that for all $x$ with $\|x\|=\sqrt{(x,x)}=1$, we have
$$\overbrace{(Ax,x)}^{=g(x)}=\Big(A\frac{x}{\|x\|},\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)=\overbrace{\frac{(Ax,x)}{(x,x)}}^{=f(x)}.$$
It is then clear that the critical points of $g$ on the unit sphere are the (unconstrained) critical points of $f$. For instance, as $f(\alpha x)=f(x)$ for all $\alpha\neq 0$, we have
$$\max_{\|x\|=1}g(x)=\max_{x\neq 0}f(x).$$
A direct computation shows that 
$$\nabla f(x)=\frac{(A+A^T)x}{(x,x)}-2f(x)\frac{x}{(x,x)}$$
By symmetry of $A$, the latter reduces to 
$$Ax=f(x)x.$$
That is, every critical points of $f$ is an eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda =f(x)$. Finally, for every $v$ and $\lambda$ such that $Av=\lambda v$, we have $f(v)=\lambda$, and thus $v$ is a critical point $f$.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: and what about non-degenerate critical points?